# Trouble creating multiple generated sticky headers using jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to integrate a sticky headers technique like the one shown here... [Persistent Headers](http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/).

I have tried to integrate it into my code and for the most part have been successful, however it isn't behaving correctly and I REALLY can't figure it out.

I'll try to explain in a nutshell what the page it is being used on does. I have a database with a table of students and another table of assessments. This page loops through a JSON object (recieved from the database via a PHP script) and then for each student in that first object fetches another JSON with their assessments. This all works fine. It does however create a fairly long page. Visually it looks like this...

[Code rendered in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gignY.png)

The code I have written based on that tutorial I posted above is supposed to clone headers specified by a class and then hide or show them based on some logic involving scrollTop the position of the element and the length of the element. This having the effect of the header sticking to the top of the page while the container it belongs to is still visible.

The problem is something is going wrong and although all the headers are shown in sequence they are way too early, they seem to hang about for different lengths of time, and these lengths do seem to correlate to how long the container it belongs to is.

So my code...

Firstly the function used to update the headers...

```
containerArray =  new Array;
positionArray =  new Array;
floatingHeaderArray =  new Array;

function updateTableHeaders() {
$(".studentContainer").each(function(i) {   
    containerArray[i] = $(this);
    var position = containerArray[i].position();
    positionArray[i] = position.top;
    var scrollTop = $("#main").scrollTop();
    floatingHeaderArray[i] = $(".floatingHeader", this);
    if ((scrollTop > positionArray[i]) && (scrollTop < positionArray[i] + containerArray[i].outerHeight(true))) {
        floatingHeaderArray[i].css({
        "visibility": "visible"
        });
    } else {
        floatingHeaderArray[i].css({
        "visibility": "hidden"
        });      
    };
});
}
```

Now the code that generates the containers, headers and tabs.

```
            $("#mainContent").fadeIn(0);
            loadMessage = "Loading data for " + event.target.id;
            $.getJSON('php/oneFullClass.php?techClass=' + event.target.id, function(data) {
                $('#mainTitle').fadeOut(0);
                $('#action').html('You are ' + actionIntent + 'ing ' + event.target.id);
                $('#action').fadeIn(300);
                $('#mainTitle').fadeIn(300);
                $('#mainContent').append('<div id="scrollTopDisplay"></div>')
                dynamicPositioning();
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    var thisPosition = positionArray[0]
                    $('#mainContent').append(
                    '<div class="studentContainer studentView" id="' + val.idStudent + '">' +
                    '<div class="studentName">' + val.name + ' ' + val.surname + ' - (' + val.form.substr(0, 1) + '/' + val.form.substr(1, 2) + ')</div>' + 
                    '<div class="floatingHeader">' + val.name + ' ' + val.surname + ' - (' + val.form.substr(0, 1) + '/' + val.form.substr(1, 2) + ')</div>' + 
                    '<div class="studentTarget"> Target: <strong>' + val.target + '</strong></div>' +  
                    '</div>');
                    $(".studentContainer").hide().each(function(i) {
                        //$(this).slideDown(0);
                        $(this).delay(i * 50).slideDown(300).fadeIn(500);
                    })
                    //Get previous assessments for this student and build tabs
                    buildTabs('php/allPreviousAssess.php?sid=' + val.idStudent, val.idStudent);
                });
            });

            $('#mainContent').append('<div id="expandAll" onClick="expandAll()">Expand</div>');
            $('#mainContent').append('<div id="collapseAll" onClick="collapseAll()">Collapse</div>');
            dynamicPositioning();
            $('#expandAll').delay(300).fadeIn(300);
            $('#collapseAll').delay(300).fadeIn(300);
           $("#main").scroll(updateTableHeaders);
```

I think that's all the info you'll need but I'll post any other code that may be referenced in this code if you think it'll help figure it out.

I have a suspicion that the problem is something to do with the animated slide in effect I am using on the 'assessment cards' messing with the position values, or possible position()'s inability to get positions of hidden elements. However, as I call updateTableHeaders() with every scroll event, this shouldn't be an issue as all animation is over by the time you are given access to the layout (there is a modal shade effect that only dissapears once all AJAX requests are complete.

I hope someone can help, this one is making me unhappy! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balloon, a library I wrote for easily making your headers stick, is pretty hassle-free. You simply make a Balloon object instance, specifying if you want your sticky headers to be stacked or replaced, and then inflate the headers by passing in the strings of their ids. Give it a try and let me know if it helped you:

https://github.com/vhiremath4/Balloon

If you find any issues with it, file a bug report on the repository, but I feel like it should do its job in your case.

Comment: Thanks for this I'll give it a go this week and see if it works, it certainly seems to fit the bill from looking at your demo.

Comment: I've had a go at setting it up and to be fair there's very few steps so I don't see where I could be going wrong but it's not working.

When I scroll a new error shows up multiple times, increasing with each new scroll refresh:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null balloon.min.js:1
k.hasClass balloon.min.js:1
(anonymous function) balloon.min.js:1
k.each balloon.min.js:1
d balloon.min.js:1
f balloon.min.js:1
e balloon.min.js:1
scrollView.onscroll`

Any clues?

Comment: What browser are you using? Also:

1.) Are you scrolling within window? If not, did you pass in the *element* of the scrolling div when you instantiated a Balloon object using document.getElementById or something similar?

2.) Did you give the headers unique ids and wrap them around a div? Did you pass those ids in when calling inflate on your Balloon instance?

3.) Did you wait for your elements to load before calling inflate? Did your scrolling div (or window) load before instantiating your Balloon instance?

I'm guessing 3 is your issue. Do you have a jsfiddle for me to play around with?

Comment: I have passed the string for the div that's scrolling, the headers have unique ID's and I am calling inflate as the last line of code in that section. It's too bigger application to replicate it in jsFiddle, it relies on a database to create the headers in the first place as you can see from the code I posted originally.

Here is my last commit to github...
https://github.com/MrCrin/OATS/blob/master/js/script.js#L501

It doesn't include your code but I've simply added this... (see next comment)

Comment: `var balloonInst = new Balloon({
     stackHeaders: false,
     scrollView: document.getElementById('main')
    }); 
    balloonInst.inflate('floatingHeader1');`

And added a line to create unique ID's in the json loop

Comment: 1.) You do not need to specify "stackHeaders", since it defaults to false (just a tip).

2.) Looking at index.php, "scrollView" is still going to be window. window is still what's scrolling in this case (the div with id "main" is not scrolling itself, it's within window which is scrolling).

3.) Make sure that all of this stuff has actually been loaded before calling the Balloon statements, especially since you're including the script tag at the top of index.php and inserting the headers on the DOM dynamically. What I would do is use that floatingHeaderArray variable you have, bind a 'change'

Comment: event to it with a callback function that then runs the Balloon variable instantiation and inflation. Then you can insert all the ids of the floating headers at once into that array and the change event will be fired once. That way you know that the headers have been loaded into the DOM before doing any of the Balloon stuff.

Comment: I will try that approach, although wouldn't that call inflate as soon as the first floatingHeader is created instead of waiting until they are all done?

Comment: Inflate should be able to be called on the same header multiple times without affecting it. So, on change to the array, just call inflate on each header in it.

Comment: Hmmm I changed things about and included the inflate call at the end the foreach loop that creates the headers and it certainly does something but the headers behave very strangely. I suspect it is something to do with the complicated DOM. If you feel inclined you could branch my code on github and see if you can fix it? If not it's going to have to wait as there are more pressing bugs to fix. :)

Comment: ^ Unfortunately, I really don't have the time to go through that. If you find that there's a bug with Balloon itself, feel free to file an issue report on the repo. It may help to take out the Balloon statements and just try them manually in your browser's web inspector's console after the web page has loaded to see if it indeed is an issue with Balloon. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to come back to this at a later date and update this thread if I get it working. I will accept your answer as it is the only one and obviously a good solution in most cases.